# element of post request not defined

Tags: javascript, express, post, postman

This is my post request code:

```
app.post('/api/carpools', (req, res) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        "admin": Joi.string().min(3).required()
    })
    const result = schema.validate(req.body)
    console.log(result)
  /* if(result.error) {
    res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message)
    return;
   }*/
   const newCarpool = {
    carpoolID: carpools.length + 1,
    admin: req.body.admin,
    members: []
   }
   carpools.push(newCarpool)

   res.send(newCarpool)
})
```

I am using tabbed postman rest client to test my post requests and this is what i am inputting:
[image]

The error is

```
{
  value: {},
  error: [Error [ValidationError]: "admin" is required] {
    _original: {},
    details: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

I have already determined that my route is defined and the error is that my JSON that i am trying to input is incorrect though I do not understand why.
This is what my sample data looks like:

```
const carpools = [
   {"carpoolID": 1, "admin": 'Sandy', "members": ['Cameron', 'Samantha', 'Stephanie']},
   {"carpoolID": 2, "admin": 'Tom',  "members": ['Luis,', 'Tyreek', 'John'] },
   {"carpoolID": 3, "admin": 'Brandon', "members": ['Joseph', 'Alex', 'David']}
];
```

The reason I have not added members to my post request code is because when a carpool is created there will be no members and therefore all I need is the admin property to be defined since the members will be an empty array regardless.
Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: have you checked the value of `req.body.admin`

Comment: it returns as undefined but I dont understand why?

Comment: perhaps your server code isn't parsing incoming `form-data` - do you have any body parser for your express server? hard to tell since you haven't posted enough of the server code to be able to determine that

Comment: no i do not have any body parser for it. How would i add one?

Comment: read the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) - my guess is, you'll want `express.urlencoded` since that's what you're sending